# transaction handling in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a `jms-message-driven-channel-adapter` receiving messages from a Queue. I am passing the message to a `router` which based on some parameter is sending the messages to spring beans configured as `Service Activators`.

I want the messages to be removed from the JMS queue only after the spring beans have processed the message. Else the message should not be removed the the queue.

I tried putting all the above flow inside the `chain` but the `jms-adapter` is not compatible with the `chain`. I am new to spring-integration. Please let me know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use (default) direct channels between all the components, the flow will run in a transaction and the message will be removed (committed) when the flow completes; just set `acknowledge="transacted"` (the default since version 4.2).

If the flow throws an exception, the message will be requeued (rollback).

Comment: What is direct channel and indirect channel. Since I am using router is it a direct channel?

Comment: A simple `<channel/>` with no queue or task executor is a direct channel. See [Message Channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html) and [Transaction Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html).